# C# classes to xsd

Tags: c#, asp.net, xsd

I am running Visual Studio 2010, I have some classes that I want to export to XSD, (My classes are like structs)

Exporting the class in xsd will allow me to send this xsd to my clients so that they can create appropriate xml, I will then use this xml to create my class objects.

I think xsd.exe allows me to that, but I cant seem to find the right parameters for the utility.

Please guide,
Thanks,
Rahil

Comment: And what does this have to do with MVC client-side validation?

Comment: my bad, I didn't removed the title of previous question

Answer (score 2):

Example

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("item", IsNullable=false)]
public ItemsItem[] items;
```

C#

```
xsd.exe -t:PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrder.dll
```

That should do what you need

Comment: sorry for the lame question again: but I have a console application, which generates .exe, and do I have to add annotation on the top of objects of my class?